# 50hz notch filter attenuating at 0hz

Tags: filter

I built a twin-t notch filter to attenuate at 50 Hz, but it attenuates at 0 Hz.

Here is my circuit diagram:

[image]

R3=15.1kohm  R2=r1=31.0kohm c1=200uf c2=c3=100uf r4=100kohm

When I gave a 1 Hz to 100 Hz sweep using a function generator with 10s sweep time and 1V input voltage, the output is like this:

[image]

The circuit is attenuating like this:

- 1 Hz 360mV
- 5 Hz 550mV
- 10 Hz 900mV
- 40 Hz 1V
- 49 Hz 1V
- 50 Hz 1V
- 51 Hz 1V
- 60 Hz 1V
- 70 Hz 1V
- 90 Hz 1V
  -100 Hz 1V

Why is it attenuating at 0 Hz?

Comment: What component values did you choose. It makes a difference.

Comment: Instead of deleting your question and posting a new one, **edit** your first question. Also the answer was already given there: the values of the components are important. I also already explained to you that this frequency sweep isn't suitable to draw conclusions.

Comment: R3=15.1kohm  R2=r1=31.0kohm c1=200uf c2=c3=100uf r4=100kohm

Comment: Was your scope AC-coupled by any chance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is with my ic tl081.so I changed it to tl084. I obtained the expected output.[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: thank you for your response